# Netsh output in csv with Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, csv

How do I format the output of the Windows command,

```
c:\netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid
```

as csv below,

```
myWifinameA,Infrastructure,WPA2-Personal,CCMP,bc:9c:31:36:05:60,80%,802.11n,10,1 2 5.5 11,6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
myWifinameB,Infrastructure,WPA2-Personal,CCMP,d4:61:2e:c6:b2:6e,75%,802.11n,5,1 2,5.5 6 9 11 12 18 24 36 48 54
```

Tried this using Python as well but I'm having trouble getting rid of the spaces.

Comment: See [wlanscan.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Wireless-networks-scanner-938fb966)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Building off this function](http://poshcode.org/2945) `Get-WifiNetwork`

```
Get-WifiNetwork | select SSID, 'Network Type', Authentication, Encryption, 'BSSID 1'
```

Seemed to collect all the information you needed.

Incase the Link goes bad in furture function code

```
function Get-WifiNetwork {
 end {
  netsh wlan sh net mode=bssid | % -process {
    if ($_ -match '^SSID (\d+) : (.*)$') {
        $current = @{}
        $networks += $current
        $current.Index = $matches[1].trim()
        $current.SSID = $matches[2].trim()
    } else {
        if ($_ -match '^\s+(.*)\s+:\s+(.*)\s*$') {
            $current[$matches[1].trim()] = $matches[2].trim()
        }
    }
  } -begin { $networks = @() } -end { $networks|% { new-object psobject -property $_ } }
 }
}
```